# How do I create a fixed button which opens a contact form when clicked using HTML & CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please check the example

[Example 1(a) , Fixed button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L28h3.jpg)  
[Example 1(b) , After Click form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2g0tI.png)

I have created the fixed button but I’m not able to open the form on click. It will be very helpful if you can provide me with any resource or reference where I can learn how to make this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Put some code buddy.. :) Show what you've tried.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty simple slideToggle function which show/hide element.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.sp').click(function() {
    $('.form-wrapper').slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

```css
.sp{
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px; right: 0px;
cursor: pointer;
width: 120px;
background-color: gray;
}
.form-wrapper{
display:none;
height: 50px;
background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sp">Slide Me Up
  <div class="form-wrapper">form goes here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank You Sir @jagdish.narkar